# Collect GPS information when app is terminated

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I have a situation in the android implementation.

There is a scenario that app is terminated/killed by user, in other words the application does not run on android device any more, can we still collect any location (GPS) information?

If not, I am thinking to implement a silent push notification to call a method to get location information and send it to server in every 10 minutes. Is it reasonable and feasible?

Answer (score 0):

On older devices you can run a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) that runs in the background and can still be running when the application is killed.

On newer devices that run Android Oreo you will have to run a [Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground). Google has added a lot of background location limitations in order to improve the battery life of devices. You can read up about it [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html).

In any case, if you run the service in the background, that service should still be running whenever the user exits the application.

Comment: referring to your last sentence..user exits the application means close the app or terminates/kills the app?

Comment: It means closes the application by swiping it from the recent applications, or by pressing the back button until the application is no longer visible. If the user goes into settings and presses "force stop", then it will also be terminated. You could run an AlarmService that checks if your service is still running to prevent that.

Comment: When the application is terminated, I am thinking to implement a silent push notification to call a method to get location information and send it to server in every 10 minutes. Is it reasonable and feasible?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work on Oreo. They're severely limiting the number of times you can poll the location of a user in the background. It'll probably work on older Android versions. Keep in mind that if you do a network request and ask locations every 10 minutes the battery will be drained quickly though.